# Recover Bluetooth password for pairing with Mitsubishi Pajero 2015

Tags: password, bluetooth-pairing

I have lost the password for my Mitsubishi Pajero 2015's Bluetooth Hands-Free Phone System that is already paired with my Samsung Galaxy Note Edge.

Is there a way to know the password used to pair my Note Edge with the Pajero?

Answer (score 0):

Your android device will not have the saved PIN anywhere because PIN is used only temporarily during pairing procedure So I think there isn't a way to reveal your PIN since it is not stored in you device. However you can remove and pair your note with pajero 2015 again.

Answer (score 0):

The PIN is provided during the pairing process by one device or the other. It's nothing you would need to have noted elsewhere.